# Is it posible to have multiple outstanding async requests?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Imagine a grid.  As the user fills out A1 cell and hits Enter to get to A2, a request goes out to the back end to look something up in a database and return the look up results back to the front end to populate the rest of the A row -- in the meantime, I want the user to be able to keep typing in A2, A3 and so on.
So the question are:

- Can you have multiple outstanding async requests that are firing one 
  after another even though the results from the earlier requests
  havent been resolved yet?  Or does each consequent async request
  somehow cancels the previous request?
- The database I am hitting is a    corporate data warehouse -- I
  imagine its extremely slow.  Is there a    limit to how long an async
  request can stay "open"?  DO browsers time    out?
- FInally, lets say I am sending out async requests #1, #2, and
  #3 -- but they get answered to in the #2,#3,#1 order -- are there
  any ramifications to that?

Thank you

Comment: If there wouldn't be multiple concurrent operations, there would be no point in asynchrony.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions. It makes answering all of them coherently and well difficult. Moreover, your last question is not very clear - ramifications for what? What are you trying to do with those requests? If you want to do something like `a + b + c` when the last request returns but `a` and `b` aren't there yet, that would be a problem. If you just want to, say, log a message to the screen or otherwise do actions that are independent of order, then there would be no problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. this is "in general" -- not specific to a library.  Just trying to understand the "under the covers" fundamentals

Comment: @alernerdev - Good deal. I've removed the irrelevant tag to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions in order:

1. Yes, you can definitely have multiple `HTTP requests` at the same time. Consider the example of a webpage. When you open any web page, multiple requests are sent to multiple places. As they are resolved, the `callback methods` defined on them keep populating the data on the webpage.
2. Yes, definitely. The request will `timeout` after some amount of time. Each browser has a `default timeout duration` for which it keeps the request open. After that timeout is reached, it cancels the request.
3. It does not matter in which order they get resolved. You will be using a `callback` based method to read the `HTTP response`. Each callback method will be specific to that `HTTP request` and should take care of itself.

Comment: In regards to 1. the HTTP/2 standard allows reuse of an open connection for multiple requests, so N resources does not always equate to N distinct connections. The browser may reuse connections for requests that aren't started until earlier requests have completed, for example. Also for 3. it might be helpful to mention how `Promise.all()` handles this issue since it's a core part of JavaScript.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Good point regarding #1. For #3 I am not sure if that is what @alernerdev is asking. If he wants to do some processing on the combined data received from all the parallel `HTTP requests` then definitely `Promise.all` is the solution but I think he is just asking if the order in which they get resolved is not correct, then how does he handle the data for each one of them.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you have multiple outstanding async requests that are firing one after another even though the results from the earlier requests
>   havent been resolved yet?

Yes.

> Or does each consequent async request
>   somehow cancels the previous request?

No.

> The database I am hitting is a corporate data warehouse -- I imagine its extremely slow. Is there a limit to how long an async request can stay "open"? DO browsers time out?

Yes, requests will eventually time out. (But I wouldn't assume a database in a corporate data warehouse is "extremely slow.")

> FInally, lets say I am sending out async requests #1, #2, and #3 -- but they get answered to in the #2,#3,#1 order -- are there any ramifications to that?

With most APIs to this (`XMLHttpRequest`, `fetch`, etc.) you'll receive the completion callbacks in the order the operations complete, not the order the operations *started*, which could indeed have ramifications if your code isn't set up to handle that.

---

For example, this code on jsFiddle shows three overlapping outstanding requests completing in random order:

```
function doRequest(reqnum, reqdata) {
    const delay = (1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000)) / 1000;
    const json = JSON.stringify({data: reqdata});
    return fetch("/echo/json/", {
        method: "POST",
        body: `delay=${delay}&json=${encodeURIComponent(json)}`
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP status " + res.status);
        }
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(`${reqnum} complete, data = ${data.data}`);
    });
}

doRequest(1, "one");
doRequest(2, "two");
doRequest(3, "three");
```

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/he84wLds/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may have multiple outstanding async requests. JavaScript is not truly single threaded as some imply. This is common when utilizing sleep functions.

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Go on, try out the sleep function and call upon it multiple times before the first request resolves. Make sure your functions are async.

Be aware of hangover error. Calling a function more than once will not reject the previous request. This can be seen in a working example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jmpcq/?editors=101

Timeout will eventually occur.